# How to make Collections from existing html in Backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm integrating Backbone.js to a project and have some problem with making sidebar's collection.

Question at issue is how to translate generated from Smarty html-markup to collection of models. The usual solution it is using templates on front side, but it's unreal in my case.

My sidebar's markup:

```html
<div class="nav-blocks">
{foreach from=$mod.nodes item=section}
  <div class="nav-block">
    <h2>{$section.title}</h2>
    <ul class="navigation">
    {foreach from=$section.nodes item=i}
      <li>{$i.title}</li>
    {/foreach}
    </ul>
  </div>
{/foreach}
</div>
```

I want to make each `.nav-block` tied to model:

```js
var Navigation = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: {
    'visible': true
  }
});
```

And when triggered event from View, the model change attribute visible:

```js
var NavigationView = Backbone.View.extend({

  el: $('.nav-block'),

  events: {
    'click h2': 'toggleVisible'
  },

  initialize: function() {
    this.model.bind('change:visible', this.render, this);
  },

  toggleVisible: function() {
    this.model.toggle('visible');
  },

  render: function() {

  }

});
```

Comment: The Model shouldn't have a visible attribute, that is a display concern and should live in the View.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply backbone views to existing html markup by this way:

```
$(function () {
    $('.nav-blocks > .nav-block').each(function(index, el) {
        new NavigationView({ model: new Navigation(), el: el });
    });
});
```

Working js fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/rJDy4/

Answer (score 1):

As the `.nav-block` divs where not created by the frontend you will have to loop in a Jquery Selector creating views and tie each to the model and setting this views EL to the JQuery returned object using `view.setElement()`